# Is it possible in Pandas to create a dataframe from another one using SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Let us say I have a dataframe `df1` and I want to create `df2` from it. Is it possible to use an SQL statement for that? Something like this.

```
df2 = dfsql("""
 select ...
 from df1
 ...
"""
```

Comment: Just use pandasql, as demonstrated here: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-tip-for-pulling-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-using-sql-queries-bbe3b39d17d

Comment: @emilioho2020 That is a nice looking library.